# To reduce the height of highchart

Tags: highcharts

i want to reduce the height of the highchart .Please the see the image below.actually i need my chart from -0.5 to 3  yaxis .can you help to reduce? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
yAxis: {
        min: 0.5,
        max: 3.0,
        startOnTick: false
    },
```

Comment: Please mark as correct and/or upvote to let others know it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
maxPadding: 0
```

[Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.maxPadding).